# Combining words in a dictionary to match a single word

Tags: string, algorithm, dictionary

I'm working on a problem where I need to check how many words in a dictionary can be combined to match a single word.

**For example:**
Given the string "*hellogoodsir*", and the dictionary: {hello, good, sir, go, od, e, l}, the goal is to find all the possible combinations to form the string.

In this case, the result would be **hello + good + sir**, and **hello + go + od + sir**, resulting in 3 + 4 = 7 words used, or 1 + 1 = 2 combinations.

What I've come up with is simply to put all the words starting with the first character ("h" in this instance) in one hashmap (startH), and the rest in another hashmap (endH). I then go through every single word in the startH hashmap, and check if "hellogoodsir" contains the new word (start + end), where end is every word in the endH hashmap. If it does, I check if it equals the word to match, and then increments the counter with the value of the number for each word used. If it contains it, but doesn't equal it, I call the same method (recursion) using the new word (i.e. start + end), and proceed to try to append any word in the end hashmap to the new word to get a match.

This is obviously very slow for large number of words (and a long string to match). Is there a more efficient way to solve this problem?
As far as I know, this is an O(n^2) algorithm, but I'm sure this can be done faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with your solution. It is no linear nor quadric time, it's actually exponential time. A counter example that shows that is:

```
word = "aaa...a"
dictionary = {"a", "aa", "aaa", ..., "aa...a"}
```

Since your solution is going through each possible matching, and there is exponential number of such in this example - the solution is exponential time.

However, that can be done more efficiently (quadric time worst case), with [Dynamic Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming), by following the recursive formula:

```
D[0] = 1 # 
D[i] = sum { D[j] | word.Substring(i,j) is in the dictionary | 0 <= j < i }
```

Calculating each `D[i]` (given the previous ones are already known) is done in `O(i)`
This sums to total `O(n^2)` time, with `O(n)` extra space.

**Quick note**: By iterating the dictionary instead of all `(i,j)` pairs for each `D[i]`, you can achieve O(k) time for each D[i], which ends up as `O(n*k)`, where `k` is the dictionary size. This can be optimized for some cases by traversing only potentially valid strings - but for the same counter example as above, it will result in `O(n*k)`.

**Example:**

```
dictionary = {hello, good, sir, go, od, e, l}
string = "hellogoodsir"
D[0] = 1
D[1] = 0 (no substring h)
D[2] = 0 (no substring he, d[1] = 0 for e)
...
D[5] = 1 (hello is the only valid string in dictionary)
D[6] = 0 (no dictionary string ending with g)
D[7] = D[5], because string.substring(5,7)="go" is in dictionary
D[8] = 0, no substring ending with "oo"
D[9] = 2: D[7] for "od", and D[5] for "good"
D[10] = D[11] = 0 (no strings in dictionary ending with "si" or "s")
D[12] = D[7] = 2 for substring "sir"
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use a [prefix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). The nodes beneath the root would be `h`, `g`, `s`, `o`, `e`, and `l`. You will need nodes for terminating characters as well, to differentiate between `go` and `good`.

To find all matches, use a Breadth-first-search approach. The state you will want to keep track of is a composition of: the current index in the search-string, the current node in the tree, and the list of words used so far.

The initial state should be 0, root, []

While the list of states is not empty, dequeue the next state, and see if the index matches any of the keys of the children of the node. If so, modify a copy of the state and enqueue it. Also, if any of the children are the terminating character, do the same, adding the word to the list in the state.

I'm not sure on the O(n) time on this algorithm, but it should be much faster.

Comment: I am not 100% sure what you are suggesting, but it seems you are trying to actually iterate all the "different build"  (i.e., for each possible solution, to actively find its end in the tree). Since there are exponential number of those - this is done in exponential time.